# Is there a django choice select form widget that allows for an optional text field

Tags: django, forms

I'm looking for a single form widget (won't be stored in a model, just appears on a form) that would render a form field like this:

```
o Option 1
o Option 2
o Option 3
o Other: TEXTFIELDHERE
```

That seems like it should be easy enough and it's probably built-in functionality but after 30 minutes of searching the docs and the net it seems my search-fu isn't working.

Comment: Third result when looking for "django choice widget other" on Google: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/863/ d:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that there's no built-in functionality to provide this ability. The link in the only comment above provides a snippet that mostly works (needed a little tweaking for Django 1.5).